# PowerShell получить последние цифры ip адреса

Tags: powershell

Нужно каким нибудь образом получить последние цифры ip адреса компьютера.

Например, если у компа ip `192.168.0.10`, то получить нужно `10`.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Вот пример получения ip: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44685122/5909792, а вот пример разделения строки и получение частей в отдельные переменные: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30617981/5909792

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Скрипт](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53876972/5909792) для получения текущего `ipv4`:

```
$ipv4 = (Test-Connection -ComputerName $env:computername -count 1).ipv4address.IPAddressToString
```

А для получения последней части `ip`, можно сделать разделение по `.`, получив список и обратиться к последнему элементу списка через `[-1]`:

```
$num = $ipv4.split(".")[-1]
```